# Getting started with postgres.app for Django application development

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin, postgres.app

I'm a newbie trying to get started with [**postgres.app**](http://postgresapp.com/).  I want to make sure I'm laying the proper foundation for the eventual deployment of a Django application to Heroku.

I've followed the steps in the [postgres.app documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation) but have a few additional questions:

1. In my development environment (on a personal osx machine) is it okay to have the Django application connect to the database as the default/root user ($USER) without a password?
2. If I wanted to set up a password for the default/root user, how should I go about doing so? I've attempted `ALTER USER [username] with password '[password]';` and modifying `~/Library/Containers/com.heroku.postgres/Data/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var/pg_hba.conf` with no success: entering `psql` in the terminal still provides unauthenticated access to the postgres shell.
3. What is the correct way to connect to the postgres.app server with **pgAdmin**.  My current setup is as follows. I suppose I'm mostly concerned with whether the `Maintenance DB` setting is correct:

   > Name: development
   >   Host: localhost
   >   Port: 5432
   >   Maintenance DB: [$USER]        # i.e., "joe"... should this be "postgres" instead?
   >   Username: [$USER]
   >   Password:

Many thanks, and any additional advice is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think OS X has a root user per se.  Semantics aside, yes it is ok to connect under your username.  By default this role will not have superuser privileges.  If you need to make superuser type changes (adding/dropping databases, granting access, those kinds of things), the customary way to do this is to use `su postgres` to switch users to the entitled user, then use `psql`.
2. By default, postgres uses unix usernames for authentication.  If you want to use  username/passwords instead you need to change settings in `pg_hba.conf` per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766464/django-mod-wsgi-postgresql-psycopg2-cant-connect-authentication-fails-but/4362410#4362410).
3. I am not very familiar with pgAdmin--wish I could help.

Comment: Thanks @Smokefoot, your answer helped me to better understand postgres privileges. Incidentally, I ended up abandoning postgres.app (though I like it a lot) and installing postgres through homebrew instead.  Both installations were challenging in OS X Mountain Lion, but the homebrew package is the one I managed to get working without errors... eventually.

Comment: Re pgAdmin: I ended up designating 'postgres' as the Maintenance DB.  it doesn't appear to make much of a difference. `The maintenance DB field is used to specify the initial database that pgAdmin connects to, and that will be expected to have the pgAgent schema and adminpack objects installed (both optional). On PostgreSQL 8.1 and above, the maintenance DB is normally called ‘postgres’, and on earlier versions ‘template1’ is often used, though it is preferrable to create a ‘postgres’ database for this purpose to avoid cluttering the template database.`